# Extracting Relevant Key Words from Tuples List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counting

I am new to Python and need help. I have several lists of words and their mention frequencies in this format:

> ResponseTweetsAug27 =[('rescue', 239), ('escape', 164), ...]
>
> ImpactTweetsAug27 = [('close', 1350), ('falling', 1267), ...]

and so on. These lists are in a file with each list on its own line.

Many of the word-frequency pairs are irrelevant. I need to comb through the lists and extract the word-frequency pairs associated with a master list of words in this format:

> key_terms = ['beprep', 'gear up', 'get ready', 'hurricaneprep', 'hurricanepreparation'...]

The goal is to display the number of times the words in the master list are mentioned. I think this will involve iterating through tuples lists but I am new to this an need a guidance. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I can move through each tuples list seperately but how would you iterate over all of them given they have different titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `itertools.chain` to return a dictionary of counts. For `key_terms`, `set` is recommended for O(1) complexity lookup.

Data from @Frynio.

```
ListA = [('beprep', 239), ('gear up', 164)]
ListB = [('get ready', 1350), ('falling', 1267)]

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

key_terms = {'beprep', 'gear up', 'get ready'}

d = defaultdict(int)

for key, value in chain(ListA, ListB):
    if key in key_terms:
        d[key] += value

print(d)

defaultdict(int, {'beprep': 239, 'gear up': 164, 'get ready': 1350})
```

Comment: Well, the better idea would be to not create two lists. The best solution here would be creating a list of lists and iterating over it like this: `for key, value in chain(*lists)`. It's more generic

Comment: @Frynio, Sure, but in that situation you should use `chain.from_iterable` instead of unpacking via `chain(*...)`.

Comment: Is there actually a performance or a security difference there? Just asking, cuz I didn't find anything in the docs

Comment: @Frynio, More performance (test it yourself), unpacking requires a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you already read the lists from the files and places them in `lists` variable:

```
ResponseTweetsAug27 = [('beprep', 239), ('gear up', 164)]

ImpactTweetsAug27 = [('get ready', 1350), ('falling', 1267)]

lists = [ResponseTweetsAug27, ImpactTweetsAug27]

key_terms = ['beprep', 'gear up', 'get ready']

for l in lists:
    for pair in l:
        if pair[0] in key_terms:
            print(pair[0], pair[1])
```

You can iterate through `lists`. Every item is a list. Then in every list (here it is called `l`) you iterate through every pair checking if the name/title, whatever you call it, exists in `key_terms`. If it does, you print it out, and the number of times they are mentioned. The result:

```
> python tuples.py
beprep 239
gear up 164
get ready 1350
```